# How to implement stochastic gradient descent

Tags: r

In stochastic gradient descent, we often consider the objective function as a sum of a finite number of functions:

```
             f(x)=∑fi(x) where i = 1 : n
```

At each iteration, rather than computing the gradient `∇f(x)`, stochastic gradient descent randomly samples `i` at uniform and computes `∇fi(x)` instead.

The insight is that stochastic gradient descent uses `∇fi(x)` as an unbiased estimator of `∇f(x)`.

We update `x` as :        `x:=x−η∇fi(x)` where `η` is the learning step.

I found difficulties implementing this in R for an optimization problem.

```
stoc_grad<-function(){
  # set up a stepsize
  alpha = 0.1

  # set up a number of iteration
  iter = 30

  # define the objective function f(x) = sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)
  objFun = function(x) return(sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x))

  # define the gradient of f(x) = sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)
  gradient_1 = function(x) return(1/2*sqrt(2+x))
  gradient_2 = function(x) return(1/2*sqrt(3+x))
  gradient_3 = function(x) return(1/2*sqrt(1+x))

  x = 1

  # create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
  x.All = numeric(iter)

  # gradient descent method to find the minimum
  for(i in seq_len(iter)){
    x = x - alpha*gradient_1(x)
    x = x - alpha*gradient_2(x)
    x = x - alpha*gradient_3(x)
    x.All[i] = x
    print(x)
  }

  # print result and plot all xs for every iteration
  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))
  plot(x.All, type = "l")  

}
```

Algorithm pseudo-code : 
[Find pseudo-code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KPmN.png)

In fact , I want to test this algorithm for optimization of a test function like Three-hump camel function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization

Other example :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJm09.png)

Comment: "I found troubles to implement this in R for an optimization problem." What did you try and what sort of troubles did you have? Stack Overflow is a great place to get free answers on specific questions (esp. if you show you've done your share of the work before asking), but it's not a free code writing service to get the full code to solve a problem from scratch. As the question's written, I expect it will be closed as "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking". If you want a good answer , show us what you've tried and what your actual specific issue with it was.

Comment: duckmayr  ,  why are you anticiping by giving false remarks !

Comment: I haven't given any false remark. When I wrote that comment, there was already one such close vote on this question (not mine). Now there is another (again, not mine). Rather than see your question closed because it isn't well formed in its current state, I'd prefer to see you edit and improve your question so that someone can give you a good answer in keeping with the rules and norms of the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: I added my code , have a  look  M. duckmayr

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: It looks like your problem is perhaps more than a programming problem. First, note that in your problem, your parameter `x` must be greater than or equal to -1 since the square root of a negative number returns `NaN` -- that's where you're running into issues. As an aside, if your objective really is to minimize `sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)`, it's clear your solution is -1. It may be better to ask at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). In any case, seeing your attempt will be helpful to potential answerers.

Comment: duckmayr : my question is clear . I want to apply stochastic gradient in a test function like those :     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization

Comment: duckmayr : there is no link between algorithm convergence & the problem in -1. The algo will simply return a value near the optimum before displaying Nan & this suffy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a lot of confusion going on here for you. Here are the two main things I see wrong so far, in order of importance:

1. Stochastic gradient descent is used when you have a lot of data, for which evaluating the objective function for all training observations at each iteration is computationally expensive. That is not the problem you're working on. See a great, short primer [here](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/OptimizationStochasticGradientDescent/)
2. When your parameter has bounded support, as here where x ≥ -1, you're going to have problems unless you guard against propagation of `NaN`s.

Here is a gradient descent implementation that will work for your problem (I've added code comments on the important changes):

```
# Having the number of iterations, step size, and start value be parameters the
# user can alter (with sane default values) I think is a better approach than
# hard coding them in the body of the function
grad<-function(iter = 30, alpha = 0.1, x_init = 1){

    # define the objective function f(x) = sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)
    objFun = function(x) return(sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x))

    # define the gradient of f(x) = sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)
    # Note we don't split up the gradient here
    gradient <- function(x) {
        result <- 1 / (2 * sqrt(2 + x))
        result <- result + 1 / (2 * sqrt(1 + x))
        result <- result + 1 / (2 * sqrt(3 + x))
        return(result)
    }

    x <- x_init

    # create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
    x.All = numeric(iter)

    # gradient descent method to find the minimum
    for(i in seq_len(iter)){
        # Guard against NaNs
        tmp <- x - alpha * gradient(x)
        if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp))) ) {
            x <- tmp
        }
        x.All[i] = x
        print(x)
    }

    # print result and plot all xs for every iteration
    print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))
    plot(x.All, type = "l")  

}
```

As I said before, we know the analytical solution to your minimization problem: x = -1. So, let's see how it works:

```
grad()

[1] 0.9107771
[1] 0.8200156
[1] 0.7275966
...
[1] -0.9424109
[1] -0.9424109
[1] "The minimum of f(x) is 2.70279857718352 at position x = -0.942410938107257"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, This helps a lot.                                                                                                             I think stochastic DG can be used in optimization but we need to divide the loss function sum in several parts.                                                                                             If you have f(x) = x^2 + y^2 . You will pick up x^2 in the first iteration only instead of the full gradient function  . then after you get some result , you will consider the second part of the sum y ^ 2 .